# Error in changing image of Notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a question. I want to update my notification to change 'pause' with 'play' image when clicked. But I keep getting this error:

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package m.com.musicbox: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for:StatusBarNotification(pkg=m.com.musicbox user=UserHandle{0} id=522 tag=null score=0: Notification(pri=0 icon=7f020067 contentView=m.com.musicbox/0x7f03003d vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x2 when=1416463928948 ledARGB=0x0 contentIntent=Y deleteIntent=N contentTitle=N contentText=N tickerText=N kind=[null]))
```

For `RemoteView`, `NotificationManager` and `Notification`, I'm using the same as before the update. Not sure if this is the correct way because I still try to find the solution. Hope anyone can help. Below is my code:

```
void updateNotification() {

    if (Utils.isStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("pause")) {
        notificationView.setImageViewResource(R.id.play, R.drawable.ic_pause);
    } else {
        notificationView.setImageViewResource(R.id.play, R.drawable.ic_play);
    }
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
}


public void setNotification() {
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

    notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, null,
            System.currentTimeMillis());

    notificationView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.notification_bar);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Player.class);
    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.contentView = notificationView;
    notification.contentIntent = pendingNotificationIntent;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

    Intent intentPlay = new Intent("m.com.musicbox.ACTION_PLAY");
    PendingIntent pendingPlayIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            100, intentPlay, 0);

    Intent intentPrev = new Intent("m.com.musicbox.ACTION_PREVIOUS");
    PendingIntent pendingPrevIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            100, intentPrev, 0);

    Intent intentNext = new Intent("m.com.musicbox.ACTION_NEXT");
    PendingIntent pendingNextIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            100, intentNext, 0);

    Intent intentClose = new Intent("m.com.musicbox.ACTION_CLOSE");
    PendingIntent pendingCloseIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            100, intentClose, 0);

    notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.play, pendingPlayIntent);
    notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.prev, pendingPrevIntent);
    notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.next, pendingNextIntent);
    notificationView
            .setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.close, pendingCloseIntent);

    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);

}
```

Comment: did you try just like this "notification.icon = R.drawable.icon;"

Answer (score 1):

You should do like this:

```
void updateNotification() {

    Notification notification;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (Utils.isStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("pause")) {
        notification = new Notification(R.drawable.pause, "String message", when);
    } else {
        notification = new Notification(R.drawable.play, "String message", when);
    }
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
}
```

Comment: I'm using custom layout and want to change the image when click on it. So I think cannot use your method because I need the reference of the original image. I updated my code on how I set the notification.